# Helmet middleware disable drop down from working and create an error in the console

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-5, helmet.js

Why when I add the helmet middleware to my app, the dropdown menus stops working and I get the following error in the console:

`Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

This is how I added helmet to my app:

```
const helmet = require('helmet');
...
app.use(helmet())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helmet maintainer here.

This is happening because of something called Content Security Policy, which Helmet sets by default. To solve your problem, you will need to configure Helmet's CSP.

[MDN has a good documentation about CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) which I would recommend reading for background. After that, take a look at [Helmet's README](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/) to see how to configure its CSP component.

To give some help specific to this question, let's take a look at one error you're seeing:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This error is telling you that the `script-src` directive of your CSP does not allow JavaScript to load from `cdn.jsdelivr.net`, and so it was blocked.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Update your CSP to allow JavaScript to load from this domain. You'd do something like this:

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: {
         useDefaults: true,
         directives: {
           "script-src": ["'self'", "cdn.jsdelivr.net"],
         },
       },
     })
   );
   ```
2. Refactor your app to avoid loading JavaScript from that domain. Probably not possible, but it is an available solution.
3. Disable CSP. This is the most dangerous option so I don't recommend it.

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: false,
     })
   );
   ```

In summary: to solve your problem, you will need to tell Helmet to configure your CSP.